# Use ACL for "profile" symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I have an application with many users. 
Each user is associated with one and only one profile. 
The profile has many global rights on many entities. 
For example,

The role "writer" has access to write, read and edit for my entity "Blog".

Roles are dynamic, I can add role in my back office. 
I think I must use Symfony Voter but I don't know how I can control if my user has the right to edit for example, an article. 
Do you have an example to make this architecture for my constraint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony documentation there is nice article about voters: [user is able to edit his own article only](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html#creating-the-custom-voter).

For deeper understanding, check [this presentation - Drop ACE, use voters](http://slides.com/marieminasyan/drop-ace-use-role-voters#/).